# Parrent element negative margin and child element seems to collabs

Tags: html, css, margin

**Greetings**

I have serius problem, I need to move div in div in a div, but it doesn't work.
My question is if there couldn't be some problems with negative margins or child element of element with margin problem.

*It seems negative margin is collapsing with positive margin in child element.*

*The margin of child element is moving parrent element.*

[*here is fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/45r76e8j/4/)
of my problem.

What I want to achieve is that:

a. Article div is overlaping main heading, I tried to avoid using absolute position, so I went for negative margin.

b. Text is margined inside of an article div. From top.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main-heading"><h1>Main Heading</h1></div>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="article">
            <div class="text"><p>Text</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also here is some of problem in css:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
}
.heading {
}
.wraper {
    margin-top: -100px;
    height: 500px;
}
.article {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: 200px;
}
.text {
    margin-top: 120px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

As I said, margin of text element seems to move article element from top as well. It's me or where is the problem, and what's the solution or workaraund? Preferably even without absolute position, but if you really need to use them, don't worry, but clear it somehow so it can be used as part of column and wont interact with upper/bottom content.

**Thank you verry much for your time**

*edit:* [picture of what I want to achieve](https://image.ibb.co/c8vaFv/sketch.png)

That black rectangle is wrapper,
cat is article
text is text, but the margins move whole article now.

Comment: not sure i understand your problem or question. Is it necessary to have the div > div > div? why not have div + div + div?

Comment: can you draw a picture of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @tom It's going to be picture background in .article and text needs to hover over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a related toppic on this, it happens in all mayor browsers, and there is a simple solution on that. There is a must to use `overflow` attribute in CSS...

I used

```
overflow: auto;
```

On parrent element, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment and what I think you're asking:

```
<div class="image">
  <p>PRESTO</p>
</div>

.image {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background-color:grey;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
}
p {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  color:orange;
  font-size:2em;
}
.image:hover > p {
  display:block;
}
```

FIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/su5aqs3p/2/

Comment: Not like this, definately, I added picture so you could see.

Comment: You want the heading to be halfway outside the container??